# Webpart-Selected Value Lost

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have written down a webpart in sharepoint 2007. I am rendering controls display in the createcontrols() .

When the Page is loaded I am able to see the layout correctly.

When I check the radio button and submit it  in the post back event the page is not able to remember the selected value. It comes up nothing has been checked.

I tried to put the code in If(!ISPOSTBACK) but no use.

I am adding the controls to the page everytime it loads.

What is the work around for my problem.

Thank you.
Hari Gillala

Comment: Can you add some code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to check.

1. Viewstate is turned on
2. For postback, you should **NOT** be doing your code in a `If(!ISPOSTBACK)` statement
3. Make sure you are doing the logic in `OnLoad` or after, if you do it in `OnInit` or `CreateChildControls`, asp.net has not populated the control values yet.